# Resize multiple objects at once

Tags: bezier-curves, scale

I have a specific shape (curve), the height of that must be adjusted to given dimensions, on an exact 1.4-2mm scale. However, its width should also be adjustable. At the moment, there is nothing wrong with this, as I can easily change its size.

However, I divided the curve into 3 parts with defined ratios (e.g., 1: 4: 1). Since I have three separate parts, I can't uniformly resize its height or width to fit the numbers above, but only one by one, not very accurately.

[image]

I tried to place the parts as child objects under an empty object, but I couldn't measure the dimensions of the empty object, only its scale, so I think this solution didn't work well for me.

I want to ask for help on how I can scale multiple objects at once with a given value. (E.g select the three objects and set them to the specified height of 1.6 mm, while making the part of the line 7 mm wide)

Comment: Parent it to the curve itself, or parent it to some dummy curve with the desired dimensions.

Comment: Thank you, it works well.